# Make a button to go back to the first of several screens

Tags: cocoa-touch, uibutton

I am creating an app which has five screens, and each screen has a button called "Home Button".

When the user presses the home button, the user should go back to very first screen.

How can I do this?

I am adding each screen over another screen like this:

```
[self.view addSubview:myview];
```

Comment: learn about navigation in iOS first. It means [self.navigationController pushViewController...] and [self.navigationController popViewcontroller...] to navigate between various screens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UINavigationController` has an array `viewControllers` of pushed `viewController`s.

You can manipulate this array instead of pop commands.

Answer (score 0):

You should have used an existing controller to manage your hierarchy between your views. But anyway, I think what you can do is calling `removeFromSuperview` on each subview and adding again your very first view. You can do this with :

```
[self.view.subviews makeObjectPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Or you can also tag the views as you add them, and remove only the tagged views to avoid removing your first view from superview.